# Dynamic Menu with laravel built in authentication

Tags: laravel

[image]I am facing a problem while building dynamic navigation menu system which comes from database,as of laravel 5.2 has implemented **Route::auth();** for basic authetication.Problem is I have includes navigation.blade.php for all papes, now how to access my homecontroller where I have use db facaed to retrive data into authcontroller.

As far I have tried code -

```
class HomeController extends Controller{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
     $unauth_menu = DB::table('menu_masters')
                    ->where('menu_auth_check','=','0')
                    ->orwhere('menu_auth_check','=','2')
                    ->Where('menu_group','like','dropin-menu')
                    ->orderBy('menu_order','ASC')
                    ->get(['menu_link','menu_target','menu_order','menu_text','menu_icon']);
     $auth_menu = DB::table('menu_masters')
                    ->where('menu_auth_check','=','1')
                    ->orwhere('menu_auth_check','=','2')
                    ->orWhere('menu_group','=','auth-nav')
                    ->orderBy('menu_order','ASC')
                    ->get(['menu_link','menu_target','menu_order','menu_text','menu_icon']);

    if (Auth::check()){
        return view('/home',compact('auth_menu'));
    }
    else{
        return view('welcome',compact('unauth_menu'));
    }
}
```

}

But this query result I am passing to front page not for authcontroller, any ideas how to implement for all pages? so front page not giving any error while login page throws above error.

Comment: So you want to have `$unauth_menu` and `$auth_menu` available on all views?

Comment: yes depending on user's authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a view composer. Open your *AppServiceProvider* in *app/Providers* and inside the **boot()** method add this:

```
view()->composer(['home', 'welcome'], function ($view) {
    if (Auth::check()){
        $menu = DB::table('menu_masters')... //Continue auth menu query
    } else {
        $menu = DB::table('menu_masters')... //Continue unauth menu query
    }

    $view->with('menu', $menu);
});
```

What this basically does is when you try to render a view with name *'home'* or *'welcome'* add variable `$menu` to them. You can read more in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers).

Comment: thanks @TheFallen, I will try and share update if it not works.

Comment: Great help @TheFallen, you saved my job,it works.. :D